# How to get key events on ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am getting click event on `ExpandableListView` by overriting `onChildClick`. This is the code

```
public class SampleChooserActivity extends Activity
    implements DownloadTracker.Listener, OnChildClickListener {

sampleListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);


  @Override
  public boolean onChildClick(
      ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
// Child clicked
}

}
```

How can I get a similar event called another key is pressed on the child and not the click event?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting `OnClickListener` to the views in the child while inflating the child in `getChildView()` method of the adapter.